# I want relevant block and template in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.2

I need relevant Block and Templates for Magento 1 to Magento 2?
Blcok -> **checkout/cart_totals**
Template -> 1. **checkout/onepage/review/totals.phtml**     2. **checkout/cart/totals.phtml**

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/cart_totals')->setTemplate('checkout/onepage/review/totals.phtml')->toHtml();

$this->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/cart_totals')->setTemplate('checkout/cart/totals.phtml')->toHtml();
```

Convert this from Magento 1 to Magento 2?

Comment: Could you please add screen shot? And enable template hints

Comment: $this->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/cart_totals')->setTemplate('checkout/onepage/review/totals.phtml')->toHtml();

Comment: $this->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/cart_totals')->setTemplate('checkout/cart/totals.phtml')->toHtml();

Comment: How to convert this into Mgento 2?

Comment: Please answer me @Pramod?

Answer (score 0):

For Magento 2 you need to look out below  files for your Magento 1 relevant file,

`<block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Totals" name="checkout.cart.totals" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/totals.phtml"`>

Block Path,

```
/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Block/Cart/Totals.php
```

Template file path,

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/totals.phtml
```